# Emily Halili book page 57 to page 62 Jmeter Recording not working

Tags: jmeter

I have downloaded a book on jmeter by following link
http://download.51testing.com/ddimg/uploadsoft/20131113/ApacheJMeter_English.pdf

It is a good book and I learnt lot from it.

IN THIS BOOK PAGE 57 TO PAGE 62 WHICH STATES THE RECORDING OF USERS HTTP REQUEST FROM BROWSER IS NOT WORKING PLEASE EXPLAIN ME THE WAY **ASSUMING THAT**

1) MY BROWSER PROXY SETTINGS WERE CORRECT.

**QuestionS**

1) How to record users action of browser in jmeter.
2) Also explain me is any "Browser Derived headers" exist that book stated on page 60 of book?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Book is very old , you should refer to [Recording Tests](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf) section on website.
2. You should use a recent version of JMeter, last one as of today is 2.11 . The version mentioned in book is WAY TOO OLD
3. In version 2.11, there is a nice feature called template, in menu select it , then choose **Recording** template. It will configure for you what needs to be setup to record. Update the port if necessary either in JMeter (to match browser if you don't want to change) or in your browser (to match jmeter), then start Test recorder
4. Read also:

   - http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP%28S%29_Test_Script_Recorder
   - https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/TestRecording210